# All child processes of a service killed with parent

Tags: ubuntu, systemd

I have a service:

```
[Service]
     ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /myNodeApp.js
     Restart=always
     RestartSec=1
[Install]
     WantedBy=multi-user.target`
```

This node app spawns another process. When the service stops, The child is killed as well. I know it's not a problem in the app because when I run `myNodeApp.js` manually and then killed it the child stays alive. I don't want the child to be killed with the service, What should I change in the configuration file to achieve it?

Comment: Do add your answer as a separate post by clicking on "Answer my own question" button below.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Under `Service` add `KillMode=process`.